How to append multiple wildcard outputs into separate lines using echo?
very very new to Linux as a whole and doing some relatively simple exercises in bash. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take multiple outputs from the wildcard character (*) and copy them into separate lines.
For example, I have 4 home files in my directory, file1, file2, File1 and File2.
I wanted to try to redirect f* into a new file called test1 so I wrote,
echo f* > $HOME/test1

when I ran
cat $HOME/test1

I got
file1 file2

on the same line. Does anyone know how to separate the lines without using nano?

A good answer below, but I would comment that you're getting ahead of yourself. Always look at the output of a command before redirecting it to a file. This way you can understand that echo f* is relying on the shell to expand the f* to your list of files, and then echo is doing just what it's name impiles, echoing the "string" that follows.  ....

Use the shell debugging flag set -x to show what the shell is doing. You'll see your version of the cmd, and then you see the shell's interpretation of the cmd, preceed with +, ie. + echo f1 f2 f3 ... and then finally, the output from echo on a separate line. (set +x to turn off).

The easiest solution, but slightly tricky, is ls -d f* >foo -- this depends on the feature(?) that ls outputting to a terminal may list in multiple columns, but when redirected (to a file or pipe) it uses only one column.
The next easiest solution is printf '%s\n' f* >foo .
The oldest/traditional solution is for i in f*; do echo "$i"; done but depending on your shell (or echo) may malfunction for filenames containing backslash. It would also malfunction for some filenames beginning with hyphen, but your particular wildcard f* won't produce any such.
But neither of these satisfies your requirement to use (only?) echo. That makes it harder for no valid reason, but can be done with an array and tweaking IFS in a subshell:
a=( f* ); (IFS=$'\n'; echo "${a[*]}" >foo)

Note this works only in shells with arrays, like bash (as you tagged) ksh zsh. The first three work in any POSIX shell (and the third even in ancient pre-POSIX systems).

echo will (or may depending on runtime or build time settings) also mangle backslashes in the file names. In some, you can use echo -E "${a[*]}" to avoid it. In zsh, echo -E - "$a" will also avoid problems with file names starting with - (not a problem here with f*)

One may also need to consider the special case where f* doesn't match any file. In zsh, you'd use print -rC1 -- f*(N) for no output to be produced in that case.

See also echo -E - ${(F)a} to join the elements of the array with line Feeds without having to modify $IFS globally. And () { echo -E - ${(F)@}; } f* to avoid the temporary variable (the list of files are passed as arguments to an anonymous function instead).

ls is really meant to be interactive if I remember.  You could use it in a script but some piece of intelligence might make it do something you don't want. find is one of the programs you're supposed to use for tasks like this.  Find has many options including output to a file so you could actually do this with no pipelining.
find -L . -maxdepth 1 -name 'f*' -fprintf $HOME/test1 '%f\n'

This translates to: Don't ignore symlinks. Find names in the current directory. Don't go into any subdirectories. These things should be names matching the glob "f*". Print the output to the file $HOME/test1 and only print the filename and a newline, strip off the path.
